# Why is WolframAlpha plotting a function and mathematica not?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Why is WolframAlpha plotting a function

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B1%2F%281%2B%28%5C%5BPi%5D*%5C%5BSqrt%5D0.9%29%2F%281-0.9%29*+sin%5B%282+%5C%5BPi%5D+%2F%5C%5BLambda%5D%29*0.1*%5E-3%5D%5E2%29%2C+%7B%5C%5BLambda%5D%2C+205*%5E-9%2C+215*%5E-9%7D+%5D](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B1%2F%281%2B%28%5C%5BPi%5D*%5C%5BSqrt%5D0.9%29%2F%281-0.9%29*%20sin%5B%282%20%5C%5BPi%5D%20%2F%5C%5BLambda%5D%29*0.1*%5E-3%5D%5E2%29%2C%20%7B%5C%5BLambda%5D%2C%20205*%5E-9%2C%20215*%5E-9%7D%20%5D)

and Mathematica dont?

```
Plot[1/(1+(\[Pi]*\[Sqrt]0.9)/(1-0.9)* sin[(2 \[Pi] /\[Lambda])*0.1*^-3]^2), {\[Lambda], 205*^-9, 215*^-9} ]
```

[image]

Comment: WolframAlpha is mostly case insensitive and Mathematica is strictly case sensitive. So replace sin[...] with Sin[...] and watch for other similar problems in the future when using Mathematica.

Comment: As said above, you used `sin` instead of `Sin`. Note that Wolfram|Alpha and Mathematica are distinct software with different input syntaxes. What works in one won't generally work in the other (or will not do the same thing in the other).

Comment: Note that in Mathematica you can use free form input, which starts with a `=`, to have it use WolframAlpha to try and figure out what you want and turn that into a valid Wolfram Language expression.